# How do I use a "range" to find a number in an array, then remove that index, and the one immediately the left of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, indexof

I have an array like this:

```
const array = ["something", "6", "somethingelse", "130", "carrot", "89", "monkey", "57", "plane", "71"];
```

I need to be able to identify any index with "number value" less than 65, and remove that index and the one immediately to the left of it.

So in this case, numbers in the array which are less than 65 are "6" and "57".

I need to remove "6" and "something", as well as "57" and "monkey".

and the resulting array would be:

```
const array = ["somethingelse", "130", "carrot", "89", "plane", "71"];
```

I have the following code so far:

```
const array = ["something", "6", "somethingelse", "130", "carrot", "89", "monkey", "57", "plane", "71"];
const range = 65 //I need to specify a range here, and not an exact number
const remove_array_index = array.findIndex(a =>a.includes(range));
if(array > -1){  //having -1 in .splice returns unintended results, so this tests if an index was found that matches the range
  array.splice(remove_array_index-1, 2);
}
```

For the code above I need to specify the number value exactly, which removes that index and the one to the left of it..... The problem is that I need to specify a range, and not an exact value.

Comment: `if(array > -1){ //... so this tests if an index was found that matches the range` - No, it does not. You compare a string of arrays with `-1`

Comment: This will also have "unexpected" behavior if the first element in the array does match the condition `< 65`

Comment: `array > -1` makes no sense. _“this tests if an index was found that matches the range”_ — No, it compares the numerical value of `array`, which is `NaN`, to `-1`; the result is always `false`. Did you mean to use `remove_array_index` here? Do you want to compare the numeric value of the numeric strings to `65`? Then `array.findIndex((num) => num < range)` is probably closer to what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way ?

```js
const array = 
  [ 'something',     '6'
  , 'somethingelse', '130'
  , 'carrot',        '89'
  , 'monkey',        '57'
  , 'plane',         '71'
  ] 
const range = 65

for (let index = array.length -1; index > 0; index -= 2)  
  {
  if (Number(array[index]) < range) array.splice(index-1, 2)
  }
  
console.log( JSON.stringify(array) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achive the result using simple `for` loop

```js
const array = [
  "something",
  "6",
  "somethingelse",
  "130",
  "carrot",
  "89",
  "monkey",
  "57",
  "plane",
  "71",
];

const result = [], range = [0, 65];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
  const str = array[i];
  const num = array[i + 1];

  if (range[0] < num && num > range[1]) result.push(str, num);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, for this great suggestion. 

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all indices and check the value and remove, if necessary.

```js
const
    remove = (array, [lower, upper]) => {
        let i = 0;
        
        while (i < array.length) {
            if (+array[i + 1] >= lower && +array[i + 1] <= upper) {
                array.splice(i, 2);
                continue;
            }        
            i += 2;
        }
        return array;
    },
    array = ["something", "6", "somethingelse", "130", "carrot", "89", "monkey", "57", "plane", "71"];

remove(array, [0, 65]);

console.log(array);
```

If you do not need the same object reference from `array`, you could filter the array.

```js
const
    remove = (array, [lower, upper]) => array.filter((del => (_, i, { [ i + 1] : v }) => {
        if (del) return del = false;
        if (i % 2 === 0 && +v >= lower && +v <= upper) {
            del = true;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })()),

    array = ["something", "6", "somethingelse", "130", "carrot", "89", "monkey", "57", "plane", "71"];

console.log(remove(array, [0, 65]));
```

Comment: `for` increments on every round. this would require an adjustment along with `splice` which changes the index of all following items.